# Why JetBrains apps not showing window content in remote desktop (Xrdp)?

Tags: debian, jetbrains-ide, archlinux, vnc, xrdp

I installed on my Debian 9.5 Stretch Xrdp for remote desktop with vnc4server. When I try to launch any app from JetBrains in remote desktop like PhpStorm, PyCharm, Rider, DataGrip or Android Studio a can't see the window content. I only see half transparent app window. The same result was in Arch Linux, but when I trying it on Zorin OS which is based I think on Ubuntu everything was OK.

Can anybody help me please? Thanks

Sorry if I have bad English

Only blank transparent window

[image: Only blank transparent window]

Comment: Not a programming question. Belongs on https://superuser.com/ imho.

Comment: Answered in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181537 (You need to add `xserverbpp=24` to the Xrdp setting on Linux box).